# How to split a vector by the end indices of every group without using loops?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

Let's say I have a vector "toSplit" of a certain size

I also a vector of indexes that I want to split the vector. For example:

```
splitInd = [ind1, ind2, ind3]
```

My goal is to have three vectors:

```
v1 = toSplit(1:ind1)
v2 = toSplit(ind1+1:ind2)
v3 = toSplit(ind2+1:ind3)
v4 = toSplit(ind3+1:end)
```

(The vectors, of course, are going to be part of a cell array). Running a loop is easy here. The question is how can I do it without running a loop (that, as we know, is not something that Matlab likes)?

Comment: `that, as we know, is not something that Matlab likes` This is not an absolute. Create *functional* code first and worry about optimizing later.

Comment: And, for the record, `mat2cell` uses a `for` loop.

Comment: "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." - [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: @excaza: Wasn't aware of that, thanks for the information. Then a `for` loop is as good as `mat2cell`. Deleted my original suggestion to use `mat2cell`. As the `for` loop is already understood, it is the best choice here.

Comment: @Daniel I don't consider it a bad suggestion, it makes for clean syntax and should already have good error checking built in. Just pointing out that looping is not inherently bad.

Comment: Well, the code IS functional. I just want it to run faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some preparation it's a job for [**`accumarray`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
%// example data
data = 1:10;
splitInd = [3, 6, 9];

%// get index array
subs = zeros(size(data));
subs(splitInd+1) = 1;
subs = cumsum(subs) + 1;

%// distributing values into cell array
output = accumarray(subs(:),data(:),[],@(x) {x});
```

---

[**`mat2cell`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is another option, shorter of code, but probably not faster.

```
output = mat2cell(data, 1, diff([0 splitInd numel(data)]) )
```

---

[image]

Comment: That's what I was typing!

Answer (score 2):

It's also not unreasonable to just loop over your much shorter `splitInd` vector:

```
splitInd = [1, splitInd, numel(toSplit)]

for split = 1:numel(splitInd)-1
    splits{split} = toSplit(splitInd(split):splitInd(split+1));
end
```

Loops in MATLAB really aren't that inefficient these days and in this case you don't even need to loop over your entire `toSplit` vector.